# In Grid and using Frame, how can I only frame the header cells?

Tags: notebooks, grid-layouts

Suppose that I use `Grid` to display a table `tab`.  I did the following, which frames all cells:

```
tab = {{"a", "b"}, {"1", SpanFromLeft}, {"2", SpanFromLeft}, {"3", SpanFromLeft}};
Grid[tab, Frame -> All]
```

and gives this output:

[image: gridall]

But, how do I programatically generate a table in which only the header cells are framed?

[image: gridsome]

(I created the above by erasing cell dividers manually, using Paint, but for larger tables, I would like to do this programatically.) Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly frame only those elements and not frame the rest. For example:

```
Grid[tab, Frame -> {None, None, {{1, 1} -> True, {1, 2} -> True}}]
```

[image]

To extend this to grids with $n$ columns in the header, you could replace the last element of the RHS of the `Frame` option with

```
Table[{1, i} -> True, {i, n}]
```

where `n` is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation:

```
Grid[MapAt[Item[#, Frame -> True] &, tab, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation of a slight variation:

```
frRow = Item[#, Frame -> 1] & /@ # &;

MapAt[frRow, tab, 1] // Grid
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]