# How to indicate table continuation in the middle with torn edge paper effect or something similar

Tags: functions, function-construction, display, table

I have a long table that I want to include on a PowerPoint page. I intend to truncate some data in the middle to ensure it fits on one page. How can I achieve this while indicating that the table continues in the middle? It would be ideal if it could be implemented with a torn edge paper effect in the middle.

[image]

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];
Grid[Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, data], Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> Center]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not ultra-realistic but ...

```
Clear["Global`*"];
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];
bpbottom = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EDki.png"];
bptop = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WwQd.jpg"];
divstop = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, j} -> True, {i, 1, 7}, {j, 1, 3}];
g1 = Grid[
   Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, 
    data[[1 ;; 6]], {{bpbottom, SpanFromLeft}}]
   , Dividers -> {}
   , Frame -> {None, None, divstop}
   , Alignment -> {Center, Center}
   , ItemSize -> {{2, 5, 5}, {{1.4}, 1}}
   , Background -> {None, {{None}, GrayLevel[0.6], 
      Blend[{White, Black, Brown}], None}}
   ];

divsdn = Flatten[#, 1] &@Table[{i, j} -> True, {i, 2, 7}, {j, 1, 3}];
g2 = Grid[{{bptop, SpanFromLeft}}~Join~data[[-6 ;;]]
   , Dividers -> {}
   , Frame -> {None, None, divsdn
     }
   , Alignment -> {Center, Center}
   , ItemSize -> {{2, 5, 5}, 1.4}
   , Background -> {None, {None, Blend[{White, Black, Brown}], 
      GrayLevel[0.6]}, {None}}
   ];

Grid[List /@ {Rotate[g1, 1 Degree], Rotate[g2, -2 Degree]}, 
 Spacings -> {0, -1}]
```

[image]

Comment: ...but I like it

Answer (score 6):

```
tearGrid[rows_, side_] := Fold[
    ImageEffect, 
    Rasterize @ MapAt[Take[#, rows] &, {1}]@#, 
    {{"TornFrame", Scaled[1/10], side}, 
     {"FadedFrame", Scaled[1/2], side}}] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];

grid = Grid[Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, data], 
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center];
```

Take first 10 rows and blur at the bottom:

```
tearGrid[10, Bottom] @ grid
```

[image]

Take last 10 rows and blur at the top:

```
tearGrid[-10, Top] @ grid
```

[image]

Take rows 7 to 15 and blur at top and bottom:

```
tearGrid[{7, 15}, {Top, Bottom}] @ grid
```

[image]

Take the first and last 10 rows and blur in the middle:

```
grid2 = Append[{ItemSize -> {3, 1}, Background -> LightGreen}] @ grid;

Column[{tearGrid[10, Bottom] @ grid2, tearGrid[-10, Top] @ grid2}, 
 Spacings -> 1 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One possibility

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### code

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];
data1 = Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, data[[1 ;; 6]]];
ve = {⋮, ⋮, ⋮};
data1 = Join[data1, {ve}];
frameIt = Item[#, Frame -> {False, True, True, True}] & /@ # &;
g1 = Grid[MapAt[frameIt, data1, Table[{i}, {i, 1, Length@data1}]]];
data2 = Join[{ve}, data[[20 ;; Length@data]]];
frameIt = Item[#, Frame -> {True, True, False, True}] & /@ # &;
g2 = Grid[MapAt[frameIt, data2, Table[{i}, {i, 1, Length@data2}]]];
```

You can paste each `g` in different power point page. Adjust sizes as needed.

Reference

[In Grid and using Frame, how can I only frame the header cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/in-grid-and-using-frame-how-can-i-only-frame-the-header-cells)

Answer (score 3):

```
blurSides = Fold[ImageEffect, #, 
  {{"TornFrame", Scaled[1/10], #2}, {"FadedFrame", Scaled[1/2], #2}}] &;

blurMiddle[n_ : 1/3] := Style[#, Magnification -> .25] & @
   ImageAssemble @ Map[List] @ MapThread[blurSides] @ 
   {Flatten @ ImagePartition[#, ImageDimensions[#]{1, n}][[{1, -1}]] & @
   Rasterize[#, "Image", ImageResolution -> 400], {Bottom, Top}} &
```

***Examples:***

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];

grid = Grid[Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, data],
  Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center];

blurMiddle[] @ grid
```

[image]

Take top and bottom 1/4 of the rasterized `grid`:

```
blurMiddle[1/4] @ grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[breakRow, rippedGrid]

breakRow[freq_ : 4, gap_ : 1, aspectratio_ : 1/8, fillingstyle_ : White] := 
 Plot[{TriangleWave[ x  freq], TriangleWave[x  freq] - gap}, 
   {x, 0, 1},
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
   FillingStyle -> Opacity[1, fillingstyle],
   AspectRatio -> aspectratio, 
   ImageSize -> {Scaled[1.1], All},
   PlotHighlighting -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Opacity[1], Black], 
   ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, Axes -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0]

rippedGrid[{fromrow_, torow_}, freq_ : 4, gap_ : 1, 
   aspectratio_ : 1/8, fillingstyle_ : White] := 
  Module[{g = Delete[#, Thread[{1, Range[fromrow, torow]}]]}, 
    ReplacePart[g, 
      {{1, fromrow - 1} ->
        {Item[breakRow[freq, gap, aspectratio, fillingstyle], 
          Frame -> {{True, True}, {False, False}}], SpanFromLeft},
      {1, fromrow} -> 
        (Item[#, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}] & /@ 
          g[[1, fromrow]])}]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
data = Table[{i, i^2, i^3}, {i, 1, 30}];

grid = Grid[Join[{{"x", "x^2", "x^3"}}, data], 
   Frame -> All, Alignment -> Center];


grid2 = Append[{ItemSize -> {3, 1}, 
     Background -> {LightBlue, {1 -> LightGray}}}] @ grid;

grid3 = Append[{ItemSize -> {10, 1}, 
     Background -> {LightBlue, Prepend[1 -> LightGray] @
        Thread[{10, 11, 12} -> Lighter@LightBlue]}}] @ grid;

Row[{rippedGrid[{9, 25}] @ grid2,
     rippedGrid[{12, 23}, 16, 1, 1/30] @ grid3}, 
    Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer this much more.